# Pythorch Error - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to write an artificial neural network with Pytorch.I'm using the MNIST dataset.
I'm new to Pytorch. I could not solve the error.
I guess the fault is here "**outfc1lrelu = self.lrelu(out)**"

Codes:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer 

device = torch.device("cpu")

#Hyper Parameter
input_size = 30 
hidden_size = 500 
num_classes = 2
num_epoch = 100  
learning_rate = 1e-8

girdi, cikti = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

train_input = torch.from_numpy(girdi).float()
train_output = torch.from_numpy(cikti)

class NeuralNet(nn.Module): #sinir agı torch u ımport etmıs oldu
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet,self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size) 
        self.lrelu = nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.02)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_classes) 
    def forward(self,input):
        outfc1 = self.fc1(input) 
        outfc1lrelu = self.lrelu(out)  
        out = self.fc2(outfc1lrelu) 
        return out

model = NeuralNet(input_size,hidden_size,num_classes) 

lossf = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epoch):  
    outputs=model(train_input) 
    loss=lossf(outputs,train_output) 

    optimizer.zero_grad() 
    loss.backward() 
    optimizer.step() 

    print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1,num_epoch,loss.item()))
```

Error part:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-70765d74f98b> in <module>
      1 for epoch in range(num_epoch): #100 tekrar yapcaz
----> 2     outputs = model(train_input) #çıktı olarak il cıktıyı versın
      3     loss = lossf(outputs,train_output) #kaybı hesapladıkçoutputsu ardından traın outputsu alsın
      4 
      5     optimizer.zero_grad() #0 a esıtledık

~\anaconda3\envs\pytorchTutorial\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    870         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
    871                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
--> 872             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
    873         # Do not call functions when jit is used
    874         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-101-58455cd48d9f> in forward(self, input)
      8     def forward(self,input):
      9         outfc1 = self.fc1(input) #girdi degerımızı alıcaz
---> 10         outfc1lrelu = self.lrelu(out) #ilk katman fc1 girdi ardından lrelu gırdı cıktı olarak(out) belli bir deger geldı
     11         out = self.fc2(outfc1lrelu) #1 mı sıfır mı tahmın etsın
     12         return out

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out' referenced before assignment
```

Why am I making this mistake? Where did it go wrong? I would be glad if you could help.

Comment: yes, it is clearly mentioned, you are using the object `out` before creating it.

Comment: On this line `outfc1lrelu = self.lrelu(out) ` what is `out` - it is not defined indeed.

Comment: did you mean `self.lrelu(outfc1)`?

Comment: Yes true. I can't believe how I overlooked this. Thanks. But now I'm getting this error. :)

Comment: which error @Alison